# How to merge array of objects using lodash

Tags: typescript, lodash

I would like to merge all objects in one array into one object, with a custom function. Using lodash's `mergeWith` works well:

```
let a = [{a: [1,2]}, {a:[3,4]}, {a: [7,8]}]
let b = mergeWith(
  a[0],
  ...a.slice(1),
  (objValue: any, srcValue: any) => {
    if (Array.isArray(objValue)) {
      return objValue.concat(srcValue);
    }
  },
);
console.log(b);
// result: {a:[1,2,3,4,7,8]}
```

This works fine but it seems wasteful to create an array copy just for that (`a.slice(1)`) - is there another way to pass that array to `mergeWith`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually mutates `a[0]`. However, if you want to mutate the 1st element, just spreading `a` would be enough `mergeWith(...a, fn)`:

```js
let a = [{a: [1,2]}, {a:[3,4]}, {a: [7,8]}]
let b = _.mergeWith(
  ...a,
  (objValue, srcValue) => _.isArray(objValue) ? objValue.concat(srcValue) : undefined,
);
console.log(b); // result: {a:[1,2,3,4,7,8]}
console.log(a[0]);  // result: {a:[1,2,3,4,7,8]}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to mutate the 1st element of the array, spread into a new object `mergeWith({}, ...a, fn)`:

```js
let a = [{a: [1,2]}, {a:[3,4]}, {a: [7,8]}]
let b = _.mergeWith(
  {}, // new object
  ...a,
  (objValue, srcValue) => _.isArray(objValue) ? objValue.concat(srcValue) : undefined,

);
console.log(b); // result: {a:[1,2,3,4,7,8]}
console.log(a[0]);  // result: {a:[1,2]}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```